# Simperium (JS) delete object from bucket

Tags: javascript, simperium

Is there a way within the Simperium JS client to delete an item from a bucket?

The other APIs appear to be able to do so.

I've tried using:

```
bucket.update(id, null)

bucket.update(id, undefined)
```

But these don't seem to do anything. There is no `bucket.delete` or `bucket.remove` that I can see.

Comment: if the underlying structure of the `bucket` is a javascript object (most likely) you can use the `delete` keyword. this hackish way may be the only way since it doesnt seem like simperium provides an API for this.

Comment: I have the same problem. There is something in the HTTP API, though. https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/#objectdelete Although I would have preferred a .delete method.

Comment: @jbabey: Deleting the object out of the current scope does nothing about removing the object from the persistent store.

Comment: @Alberteddu: yeah, the HTTP API can do it. But that kind-of defeats the purpose of a JS abstraction :) I'm hoping it's just an oversight (since the python version can delete objects out of a bucket).

Comment: I asked them on twitter, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update that id, the 'local' callback for that id should also return null. That should delete the object from the bucket.

Comment: That might be something you might want to put into the documentation. Either that, or allow explicitly passing `null` into update to delete the object.